# Sort lexicographically in bash

Tags: bash, sorting

I want data to be sorted in the way Python sorts it, comparing ASCII values. But `sort` command seems too clever for that. Take a look. Since `'.' < '9'`:

```
$ sort
.
9
^D
.
9
```

and :

```
$ sort
1.
19
^D
1.
19
```

These two are fine. But for some reason, if I just add characters to the ends:

```
$ sort
1.c
19z
^D
19z
1.c
```

Probably it tries to read that as a number or something. I don't want that, I want it to sort stuff comparing ASCII values of each character. Couldn't find such an option in `man`, any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The described behaviour is probably an effect of locale. Turn off locale settings for sort:

```
$ echo '1.c
19z ' | LC_ALL=C sort
1.c
19z
```